# The HTTP version of my websites take a long time to resolve, while HTTPS versions instantly resolve. How to debug it?

Tags: ssl, performance, website

I create many websites for my customers.

And I register domains via different registrars.

And I have a couple of VPS servers, distributed in different data centers.

However, I see this weird behavior.

When I use `example.com` which translates into `http://example.com` I see that it takes a lot of time and usually the first time it won't respond and times out and on the second refresh it works.

However, if I explicitly write `https://example.com` it instantly brings up the website.

Here's my configuration:

- Debian bullseye
- Nginx with HTTP redirection
- Docker

How can I debug this? I have no clue on where to look and what too check.

Comment: They do resolve in identical time, because it's the same domain name. It's the connection/session lag you're observing. Start from the point where you subjectively measure the time needed to connect to the target port, comparing `telnet example.com 80` and `telnet example.com 443`. Then, if these two times will be also the same, you could start exploring the phases using curl.

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to find out which part of the request takes the most time.

Comment: There's probably something redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS, and this component is slow.